# Visual Studio 2010 - C# editor more cumbersome than VB.NET editor

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I traditionally work in VB.NET, but have been asked to code the latest project in C#.

This is fine as I can work in either language, having had to frequently translate C# code to VB in the past and I've no qualms about developing in either.

My issue is with the Visual Studio editor and how many of the tasks that have traditionally been automated for me while writing VB.NET code are missing when writing C# code, or involve a larger variety of key-presses.

For example, creating a new #region or function...

In VB.NET creating a region involves typing <kbd>#</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, at which point intellisense kicks in and shows me `#Region`. I press <kbd>space</kbd> and `#Region` is auto-completed, thus allowing me to type the region name, then click <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the closing `#End Region` is automagically added.

In C#, I type <kbd>#</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>... and nada.. I have to either click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and select `#Region` from the list of snippets to achieve the same effect.

Similarly when writing functions in VB.NET ... the autocomplete creates the structure in seconds, whereas C# involves having to manually add the brackets etc, adding precious seconds to the development process. (or perhaps there is another shortcut key combo)

These are just two examples, but there are many others where the short-cuts that the VB.NET editor provides make coding much faster than the C# editor.
I'm pretty shocked actually as C# is so often lauded for being "better" than VB.NET.

Anyway rant over.

My question is, are there any plugins which allow autocomplete on the C# editor in the same way as provided to the VB.NET editor?

Comment: I'm convinced the guys on the Visual Studio VB.NET team go in and turn off features on the C# side when that team isn't looking. Hear a lot of rants about what are seemingly simple things like this.

Comment: In c# if you type in #region and hit tab, it inserts the #endregion and places the cursor in an edit box to type in the name.  Also, you can select lines of text, right click and choose 'Surround with...' and #region is one of the options.  So it may be a little different than the VB editor, but not that much.  For methods, just create a code snippet and then you can type the snippet and hit Tab to fully expand it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resharper.........................................................................

Comment: looks like it might do the trick .. will try it out tomorrow morning. Thanks! (and if it works will mark question as answered) :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're just used to coding in VB.NET. As for your comment about C# being viewed as superior to VB.NET, I think you need to make a distinction between the language and the editor, because the two are not intrinsically tied together.

It's possible that C# doesn't offer the same auto-completion features that VB.NET does, but I think productivity comes down to how comfortable you are with the language. Even without those auto-completion features, I can code a heck of a lot faster in C# than I can in VB.NET, and that's because I'm used to how C# behaves, and I know how to flow with the editor.

In my honest opinion, I think you need to get used to coding in C# before you can make a true assessment of how coding in either language impacts your productivity.

**EDIT**

If you're looking for something free that's comparable to Resharper, I would suggest taking a look at `CodeRush Xpress`. There's also a full-featured version of `CodeRush` that retails around $100 cheaper than Resharper.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to do some digging around under Tools... Options > Text Editor > C# and check the configuration there. Some things can be tuned from there that may have been missed if you configured if you setup your environment as VB.NET initially.

You might also look into the [Visual Studio Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) which have some extra auto-complete bracket options available to it, as well as a few other features that could help.

Comment: I had a look around the options alright, and all the relevant ones seem to be ticked, but none (that I can see anyway) are for replicating the sort of functionality I mentioned previously.

Comment: My apoligies, I thought brackets were configurable under options for completing and auto-inserting in some of options, I think. Ctrl-K, X for Snippets has some of the region items and others you mentioned. But yes, it's definitely missing a few

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper does a lot to C# that Visual Studio already does for VB.NET for free.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet for inserting a private method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Private Method</Title>
            <Shortcut>pvtm</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for a private method</Description>
            <Author>Your Name Here</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Return Type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>void</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>name</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Method name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyMethod</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ $name$ ()
    {
        $selected$ $end$
    } //end method $name$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

I'm sure it can be improved, but then you can just type pvtm and hit tab and voila!  You get a whole method.  Again, not the same as the VB editor, but pretty close.  Some might say better.

This is an old snippet and I think it will work in VS2010, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big proponent of CodeRush from [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/), which serves largely a similar purpose to Resharper.  In Code Rush, if I want to put in a region, I select the code I want to region off and hit Ctrl-3, and the regioning is created with a caret on the region name that then type in.  Its behavior is also very configurable regarding all of its templates (which are like VS Code Snippets on steroids).

Full disclosure, though -- it's an investment because the express version has very little functionality as of Visual Studio 2010.  You'd also do either this or ReSharper -- probably not both.  I had both installed at one point and I seem to recall them not playing very nicely together.